# How to execute hex code in linux

Tags: executable

It is as simple as the title says. I can easily execute it in windows with a `.com` file but how would i do it with Linux. Basically i want to write to a file in hex and then run it. On Linux.

Comment: Your question makes no sense to me.  Are you trying to convert hex to rgb or something?

Comment: @bc2946088 bruh

Comment: Glad you got your answer you're looking for.  Referencing HEX in your question made me think of base16, and I wasn't sure what 'code' you were talking about.  I understand now, you have a script you want to execute.  I'm not sure the reference to hex in your question makes sense, but you marked an answer as complete, so all is good.

Comment: @bc2946088 actually i did mean base16 but it seemed to work anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
chmod +x your.hex.file
```

execute with

```
./your.hex.file
```